# Pass a tuple as arguments for a closure

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

I want to write a function `apply_tuple`, such that:

```
apply_tuple(new Tuple(x1, x2, ... , xn), f)
```

Returns:

```
f(x1, x2, ... , xn);
```

How can I do this in groovy?

Comment: You want it to return the closure with the tuple applied but not executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
def apply_tuple(Tuple t, Closure f) {
    // inject is just a groovy name for the typical 'fold'
    Closure argumentsApplied = t.inject(f) { Closure c, Object tx ->
        c.curry(tx)
    }
    argumentsApplied()
}
```

Or, if you did not mean to already evaluate `f` but instead where interested in the resulting function, then just remove the `()` at the end of `argumentsApplied`. Here is an even shorter version (but less readable IMHO) that does just that:

```
def apply_tuple(t, f) {
    t.inject(f) { c, o -> c.curry(o) }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. Have a close look at the result I want, particularly regarding the taking of a Tuple as an argument.

Comment: Then please be more specific in regard to the result you want. In what way does my proposed solution not fit your requirements? You neither want the result of f applied to the elements of the tuple as arguments, nor do you want a function where the first parameters are fixed to be the elements of the tuple. So what else is it? I just don't see a third option in your question.